# How to get the type of a variable declaration when using Swift macros

Tags: swift, macros

I wanted to know how I can get the type of a variable when using swift macros. Consider the following example:

```swift
@MemberwiseReimplementation
struct Person { 
    var someProperty = "John Doe"
}
```

expected output:

```swift
struct Person { 
    var someProperty = "John Doe"

    init(someProperty: String) {  // << there is no way for me to know it's a "String"
        self.someProperty = someProperty
    }
}
```

The issue here is that I know no way of getting the type of `name` unless I check for each type of `<TypeName>` `LiteralExprSyntax` there is and have a table that corresponds to the type.

Is there no way I can rely on the compilers type inference and obtain the type information? Or perhaps use `type(of:)` and parse that into swift code somehow? To my knowledge, there is no way to extract the type information from a pattern binding unless it's explicitly given. Does anyone know a way?

Comment: In the [Swift Syntax repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax/tree/main/Examples/Sources/MacroExamples) there are a lot of examples.

Comment: It's [not currently possible](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-arent-macros-given-type-information/66893) to get exact type information in macros [because there isn't yet any API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0382-expression-macros.md#macro-argument-type-information) to provide that information, so it remains a "Future Direction" for the macro system. At best, you can figure out types from surrounding context.

Comment: The macro you exemplify - `MemberwiseReimplementation` - is attached to the `Person` struct, thus is has access to all property declarations, including the one for `someProperty`.  And form that property declaration, you can find the type you're interested into.

Comment: @Cristik Yes but wouldn't I need to check what sort of literal it is if the type annotation isn't given? Id have to check for each type of literal one by one. Eg. `if type is IntegerLiteralSyntax.self else if type is StringLiteralSyntax.self ...` etc etc. Or do you know of a better way?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to check for all possible literal syntax types... The reason is currently the macros receive only the syntax tree of the piece of code the macro was place onto. After re-reading your question, seems you're asking for a more direct alternative to this, I also am not aware of any other way, at this moment.